# Excel - How do I make the text in a cell flow over into the cell below

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: Illustration of how I would like Excel to flow.]

I want the text in a cell to flow vertically, that is, flow over into the cell below. When writing in a simple text that is longer than the column width the text flows over automatically into the next column without changing the next column's width. It would be nice if this worked vertically also so that row height would not change. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlight both cells, then click the "Wrap text" and the "Merge & center" buttons.

[image]